# Increase hover area of SVG element

Tags: javascript, css, events, svg, hover

There is an SVG element like this  -

```
<path d="M0,5.26429605180997L6.078685485212741,-5.26429605180997 -6.078685485212741,-5.26429605180997Z" transform="translate(100,100)scale(0.8)" style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);"></path>
```

Now, this element is so small that hovering over it is very hard.

How can I increase the hover area (keeping the area of this element same) so that even if the mouse points about say 2 px away, the hover event gets fired?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Increase your **Stroke width** and make **Stroke Opacity** to **0**. If **0** doesn't work then make it **0.01**

Comment: How is this the accepted answer when stroke width has nothing to do with the hover area?

Comment: Increasing the stroke-width would enlarge the area that can be hovered, but this isn't a great solution. It can't be used if the SVG makes use of a stroke already for visual purposes.

Answer (score 12):

My recommendation is to create another svg element that is completely transparent that is over that object that handles the hover events. For example

`<path d="M0,5.26429605180997L6.078685485212741,-5.26429605180997 -6.078685485212741,-5.26429605180997Z" transform="translate(100,100)scale(2.0)" style="fill: rgb(0, 0, 0, 1.0);"></path>`

I don't know if increasing the hover area on an element the way you describe is possible. (If it is I would love to know how.)

Comment: You don't need to fiddle with adjusting the transform.  Just give it an invisible stroke that is the thickness you need.

Comment: Here's an example of this: http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/interactivity/hover-invisible-stroke-compat.svg (hover effect triggers when the mouse cursor gets closer than 20px to a shape).